# Help correct my misunderstanding regarding the measure of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've confused myself over something elementary, so I'd appreciate it if someone can correct my misunderstanding.

Consider the unit ball $B^{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. It is clear that $B^{n}$ does not admit a product representation $U_{1} \times \dots  \times U_{n}$ of open sets $U_{i} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

But $B^{n}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and it has an $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a separable space, the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B} \times \dots \times \mathcal{B}$ is the same as $\mathcal{B}^{n}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is just the Borel sets. I'm tempted to say, then, that $B^{n}$ must admit such a product representation, even though I know this is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all elements of the product algebra are products of measurable sets of the factors. The product algebra is *generated* by these basic measurable sets, meaning the elements of the product algebra are unions and intersections of products of measurable sets in the factors, but not necessarily equal to a product of measurable sets in the factors.

The example you gave is a good one. The ball is not a product of open sets, but it is a countable union of products of open sets.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) on the product measure.

Comment: Thanks. This gives rise to somewhat of a problem for me. I don't know if you are familiar with statistics, but I am proving a result that says if a random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed over some region $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then all the univariate factors of the random variable are independent and uniformly distributed (e.g., $X_{i}$ uniformly distributed on some $R_{i}$) if and only if $R = R_{1} \times \dots \times R_{n}$. Am I correct to infer that this result is always true if $R$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, since it always admits such a product representation?

Comment: Well, as we said $R$ does not always admit such a product representation if it is measurable. And the coordinate random variables need not be independent if the region if not a product. The ball is an example where they are not independent. If $x^2\geq \frac{1}{2}$, then $y^2\leq \frac{1}{2}$, so $Pr[x\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},y\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]\neq Pr[x\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]Pr[y\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$.

Comment: I think I know what I'm hung up on. I agree with you that the unit ball is a countable union of products of open sets... but can it not be thought of as a product of sets generated by open sets in each component? That is, these component sets won't be open, but they may be just obtained in some way using the Borel sets? So that we can represent it as a product of measurable sets (in each component)?

Comment: If it were a product of measurable sets, it would essentially be a cube with some linear chunks removed. It can't be represented as a product. I'm not sure if that answers your question because I'm not quite sure I understood it.

Comment: Thanks, you've already clarified a lot for me. What you said makes sense, the only reason I'm not sure is because Folland defines a product $\sigma$-algebra to be generated by products of measurable sets. But I think I've already convinced myself this doesn't mean all sets in the product algebra are products of measurable sets.